# eclipse or android studio not recognize my phone on usb debugging mode

Tags: android, debugging, usb

I have huawei ascend G7, I turn on USB debugging on my phone and connect it to my PC using a USB cable.
the problem is that I have to turn on Usb storage mode if I want eclipse or android studio recognize my phone.
and you know it cause mounting and unmounting sd-card!

is there any way to prevent from mounting or unmounting sd-card? or force eclipse or android studio to recognize my phone on [charge only] mode?

Answer (score 0):

try using this PDAnet .. generic device driver for all android devices

http://www.topnotchtablets.com/installADBdriver

Answer (score 0):

You can try this(Chinese):

http://wenku.baidu.com/link?url=E3u1b91YrLov3e58BzOSMiYFWMOCbPzsJCLnnE-U1IyEbsur60T-QUGTa8pTMwsrS_83B_QzzvpwfkZHcbVU-kP8PYsh-52b4j5x0cgyemO

or you can use some third party software such as "豌豆荚" to help to connect you phone, but I don't like them, they always launch themselves and send some notifications.