# Android Studio doesnt recognize my device - Nexus 6P

Tags: android-studio, adb, windows-10, usb-debugging, nexus-6p

I am struggling to figure out the problem with my device not being recognized in Android Studio. However I do see it from file explorer and can browse the device files.

- OS: Windows 10
- Device: Nexus 6P

Yes, I did some research before posting this question, so I'll enumerate what I tried:

- Enabled USB Debugging
- Installed Google USB drivers from the SDK manager
- Intalled HiSuite(apparently including some device drivers)
- Switching between MTP/PTP
- Restarting Android Studio several times
- Restarting my computer several times
- Every USB 2/3 ports of my computer
- Tried updating drivers from device manager(however it did not suggest anything)
- adb kill-server / start-server

Any suggestions would be greatly welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just to be clear regarding the bounty - adb devices **does** show my device is connected.

Comment: http://adbdriver.com/downloads/ try this driver

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html#Troubleshooting

Comment: is a problem already solved?

Comment: Have you tried to change your usb data cable? If the problem is not data cable, try to install Snappea, or wondershare mobile go

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, installing 'Google USB Drivers' from the SDK Manager doesn't actually install them!

You have to go to:

'C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\'

- right-click on 'android_winusb.inf' and install.

Comment: this didn't work for me, windows 10 assures me my drivers are up to date and don't need any further work.

Comment: @SlashJ is a problem already solved?

Comment: There is no install option when the file is right clicked in Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I make sure that I've installed google's usb_driver. Either through the SDK or what SlashJ said:

> Apparently, installing 'Google USB Drivers' from the SDK Manager doesn't actually install them!
>
> You have to go to:
>
> 'C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\'
>
> right-click on 'android_winusb.inf' and install.

- SlashJ

After that's done:

- Insert your device into your PC
- Open **device management**

  1. Click start > run **devmgmt.msc**
  2. Right click my PC > manage > devices in left panel
- Check if there's a tab **android device** and look for your device or an ADB Interface, Otherwise just search for your device
- Right click your device and **Update Driver Software**
- **Browse my computer for driver software**
- **Let me pick from a list**
- Search for google or android in the left pane.
- And select ADB Interface in the right.
- Continue installation and it should work now.

You can try to unplug and re-plug your android device.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use ADB over Network but it depends what Android version you have. 
In `Developer options` you should see `ADB over network` section if not then sorry for this unhelpful advice.

Answer (score 2):

If you have already tried all those steps , i would like you to [install pdaNet software](http://pdanet.co/a/) . This will automatically detect and repair the driver and you can find device in Android Studio.

*This has worked for me*

**SO references :**

[Android studio doesn't list my phone under "Choose Device"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225927/android-studio-doesnt-list-my-phone-under-choose-device#answer-25226019)

[eclipse or android studio not recognize my phone on usb debugging mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801195/eclipse-or-android-studio-not-recognize-my-phone-on-usb-debugging-mode)

References for installing the drivers and enabling USB debugging is [available here](http://michaelcrump.net/enable-usb-debugging-with-nexus-5-for-android-studio/) for reference , you could cross check with as well.

Reference 2 : [Installing pdaNet](http://www.topnotchtablets.com/installADBdriver)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

check for SDK platforms in Android Studio whether you have installed the Android 6.x(N), Because Nexus got Android N updates, so it may be one of the issue you faced...

Answer (score 2):

When I had this problem what I did was install the drivers manually. What you do is download the drivers from the google website NOT with Android Studio then you go into device manager and right click on your nexus. Then go to drivers tab and hit the update then manually find drivers on computer. Navigate to the downloaded drivers and click on them. Device manager will install your drivers and should fix the problem. Also for drivers you may want to try [this](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/) or [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) driver Also please post these kinds of questions on the [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem with my Wiko phone, **I had installed the wrong usb driver** and I could not do it manualy.

> 1. In developer mode, enable the usb debuging
> 2. Try to update your driver with **apk installer for Windows 10** even if it is already installed:

[APK DRIVER](http://adbdriver.com/documentation/how-to-use-android-adb-driver-installer-for-windows-xp-vista-7-8.html)

This tool permits to install automaticaly the right driver.

*Have a look to my previous question fo further details:*

[How can I run my ionic app on a physical device (Wiko phone) on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38729420/how-can-i-run-my-ionic-app-on-a-phisical-device-wiko-phone-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you also have to enable developer mode on the device.
[Here's a walkthrough](http://www.howtogeek.com/129728/how-to-access-the-developer-options-menu-and-enable-usb-debugging-on-android-4.2/)

Answer (score 1):

i just have that problem and anything works for me
what help me is to click a lot of time on the **build number** (setting-about phone-build number) and magic happens :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check in Android Studio Run tab->Edit Configurations->Target set to USB device.
if that doesn't work, try updating Android Studio, and/or device's firmware, also here is a similar question, involves a nexus and windows 10: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31938193/3817308

I hope this help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you installed adb driver. If your device is displayed in device manager but not as a ADB device, try these steps

1. Go to Control Panel and open Device Manager.
2. Find the device
3. Right click the device and select properties.
4. Select Driver tab, then click the Update Driver button.
5. Choose Browse my computer for driver software.
6. Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer
7. Browse for the .inf driver file. Open and Next.
8. Select ADB interface from device list (i can't remember the exact name)
9. Install

Answer (score 0):

There's another another Stack post ([Cannot see Nexus 6P for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747550/cannot-see-nexus-6p-for-debugging/34347725#34347725)) you might want to try.

1. You need to manually download the driver here (http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)
2. Go to "Devices and Printers", right-click on "MTP", and choose properties.
3. Click "ADB interface", then click "Properties"
4. Go to "Driver" tab and update driver with the file you just downloaded. (Make sure you unzip them first)

Comment: Devices and Printers? There is not such thing. Thanks for nothing. And your link is also dead.